# adding key-value pairs from command to a json object without duplication

Tags: jq

I want to add key-value pairs to a JSON object in the command line.

```
$ jq -c -n -f /dev/stdin --arg a '"1"' --arg b '"2"' <<< '{u: "u", a: $a, b: $b}'
{"u":"u","a":"\"1\"","b":"\"2\""}
```

In the above example, given the arguments of --arg a '"1"' --arg b '"2"', I have to manually add "a" and "b" to the template (the string from stdin). This duplication is not desirable.

How can I make the template independent of the arguments to be passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $ARGS.named :

```
jq -c -n -f /dev/stdin --arg a '"1"' --arg b '"2"' <<< '{u: "u"} + $ARGS.named'
```